# Using returning id of last insert into other queries in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to use queries like given below? If there is any better way to do it please let me know.

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (...) RETURNING id INTO t1_id;

UPDATE table2 SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2....WHERE id = t1_id;

UPDATE table3 SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2....WHERE id = t1_id;
```

Thanks

Comment: That's fine. If you want to get fancy you can use a writeable CTE, but I do not advise it unless you really need to.

Answer (score 1):

Queries are perfectly fine and this is the simplest way to use them.